# Wpf single exe - using application and user properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I've recently upgraded my wpf application to     core 3.0.

The application uses property settings to save and read specific application settings.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.AllowZoom = true.
```

These properties are saved to a config file that the exe reads from. This works fine, however if I build the application as a single exe it cannot read or write to the properties file.

Anybody know a work around?

Comment: What exactly does "cannot read or write to the properties file" mean? Are you getting an exeption or what happens?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. If you are calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` and use the default provider, the `user.config` file in the path returned by `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath` should be updated as expected.

It's worth mentioning that when you use the `PublishSingleFile` option to create a single executable (`.exe`), a temp folder will be created on the first run. You can read more about this and the impact it may have on your app [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/).